# How to get total number of wordpress installs on websitepanel?

Tags: wordpress, websitepanel

I'm trying to collect total number of wordpress installs on websitepanel. I reviewed the websitepanel database but looks like that information is not stored in it. Any help on collecting this data would be helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: @disinfor trust me extracting information from websitepanel requires good knowledge of sql. I couldn't find any wordpress related info in websitepanel schema, however UI has the option to install and manage versions. Somebody must have already extracted that info or figured out where exactly that info is stored in the tables.